# textbox search through array with keys and display closest results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So, I'm not sure if there is a better method of what I'm trying to do, but effectively I have an array of about 12,000 elements, and each has a key in the format of:

```
var arrayObj = {

"blue": 'key1',
"orange": 'key2',
"red": 'key3',
"black": 'key4',
//ect... 

}
```

I have a textbox and using javascript each keypress should check for new results. I'd like to display the top 5 most relevant results from the array based off of what is typed within the textbox. Example, if I type `bl`  the results should be `blue` and `black` etc.

```
$('#searchBox').keypress(function() {

    madeSearch();

}

function madeSearch() {
    var isInArray = [];

    if($.inArray($('#searchBox').value, arrayObj) > -1) {
        //get arrayObj entry and key. 
    }
}
```

I'm just quite confused because I've never worked with javascript array keys before and I'm not sure how to attain them and what the best practices are for searching through an array of length 12,000...

Any tips or help? Thanks.

Comment: So you want autocomplete with "black", "red", "blue" only? Is "key1", "key2" important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this what you looking for you can use it in local by providing your array or ajax

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

**Ajax lookup:**

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/countries',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

**Local lookup (no ajax):**

```
var countries = [
   { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
   // ...
   { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the keys:

```
Object.keys(arrayObj)
```

To perform prefix search in the above key list,

```
Object.keys(arrayObj).filter(function(key){ return key.substring(0, input.length) === input })
```

If you want to optimise this further, look into data structures like Trie.

[JavaScript Trie Performance Analysis](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/)